# settings icon missing in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: gnome, 18.10, gnome-control-center

in the system menu on the top bar beside the lock button there is supposed to be a gnome control center icon, recently it just disappeared on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: Are you able to launch the '*Settings*' application from Activities overview / 'Show Applications' or Terminal?

Comment: at the beginning no, but after reinstalling it I could but just did not appear then I reboot and it was there again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I  just reinstall it

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

then rebooted

Comment: it also re-installs all the default apps.

Comment: alternatively, log out and log back in - or simply `sudo systemctl restart gdm`